# What determins the list of supported cipher suites?

Tags: java, ssl, encryption

The method `getSupportedCipherSuites` returns the supported cipher suites. 
Quoting the documentation:

> ```
>  * Returns the names of the cipher suites which could be enabled for use
>  * on an SSL connection created by this factory.
> ```

Based on what a cipher suite is supported or not ?

Comment: Probably based on availability, i.e. presence of code that implements that suite. That in turn might depend on the JVM version as well as any libraries on the classpath.